# How to get base URL of PHP file after htaccess redirect that doesn't change the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and I have a PHP script that is redirecting to two directories /game/ or block/ I want to use curl to open files in one of the directories.

This is my code for getting the URL:

```php
function is_https() {
    // apache
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        return true;
    }
    // heroku
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'])) {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT'] == 443 || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https';
    }
    return false;
}

function get_self() {
    return 'http' . (is_https() ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

function main() {

    $addresses = json_decode(file_get_contents('ip.json'));
    $blocked = in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $addresses);
    $url = get_self() . ($blocked ? "/block/" : "/game/");
    $url .= $_GET['q'];
    
    echo $url;
}

if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    main();
}
```

The problem is that when I access the file locally for testing when I try to access:

```
http://localhost/~kuba/jcubic/support/order/app/index.js
```

It got this URL:

```
http://localhost/~kuba/jcubic/support/order/app/index.js/game/index.js
```

the PHP script and .htaccess file are located in:

```
http://localhost/~kuba/jcubic/support/order/app/
```

how can I get the URL of the index.php the path where the .htaccess file is located?

I need this to work as the root directory `https://example.com/` the same as in any directory. I don't know where this script will be executed.

Comment: @anubhava when I access the URL http://localhost/~kuba/jcubic/support/order/app/index.js the PHP file is in http://localhost/~kuba/jcubic/support/order/app/ and I should get the URL http://localhost/~kuba/jcubic/support/order/app/game/index.js I can just remove the file because the files can be in nested directories. So basically what I want is the location of .htaccess file from the browser.

Comment: Instead of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, try and use the "difference" between `__DIR__` and the document root - `substr(__DIR__, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))`

Comment: @CBroe I can't use this because I use the home directory `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is `/var/www/html` and it has nothing to do with `__DIR__`. At least on my local machine.

Comment: Is it worth the effort of trying to do this "dynamically" in the first place, I wonder. Having a base URL _specified_ in your configuration, would be a lot easier ... _"how can I get the URL of the index.php the path where the .htaccess file is located?"_ - I don't think you _can_, really.

Comment: @CBroe Actually I've found a way, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, first I was trying using htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1&f=%{SCRIPT_NAME} [L,QSA]
```

but the script name was empty. But it turns out that the PHP variable:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
```

Contain the URI of the php script. So I all have to do is to remove index.php:

```php
function get_self() {
    $uri = preg_replace("/index.php$/", "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    return 'http' . (is_https() ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $uri;
}
// is_https is in the question
```